# How to determine multiarch tuple in autoconf

Tags: debian, autoconf

Suppose the Debian development package of libfoo installs headers in `/usr/include/$multiarch-tuple/foo`, where  `$multiarch-tuple` is something like `x86_64-linux-gnu` (this is using Debian's multiarch specification, see [1]).

I would like my configure script to add `-I/usr/include/$multiarch-tuple/foo` to `CPPFLAGS`.  Is there any way to do this using autoconf?

Thanks!

[1] https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and simplest simple answer would be to set *CPPFLAGS* in the environment before running *configure*. For example:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/$multiarch-tuple/foo ./configure
```

However if Multiarch uses pkg-config then it might
slicker might be to have *configure.ac* pick out the flags from the installation. To see if Multiarch uses pkg-config, try:

```
pkg-config --cflags-only-I Multiarch
```

And of course you can combine that with the first solution:

```
CPPFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags-only-I Multiarch) ./configure
```

Convention changes on how to do this when automake is used, but thankfully, you didn't mention that.